# jython to python version mapping

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython, jython-2.7

Jython is an implementaion of python. Is there any way to find the version of python that is being supported by a particular jython jar.

eg: Few posts in the web say that Jython 2.5 supports python 2.5

Similarly I want to know the jython version that supports python 2.7.14 or more.

It would be helpful if the version mapping can be referred to in any user-guides or pages.

Comment: I don't think there are any explicit "support mappings" between bugfix (micro) versions of implementations. CPython 2.7 and Jython 2.7 (minor version) are supposed to be equivalent, in principle. The latest bugfix version of CPython is 2.7.15. The latest Jython is 2.7.1. That's basically it.

Comment: See https://bugs.jython.org/issue2694