# What is the relevant version of Python for Jython 2.7.1?

Tags: python, version, jython

Due to some security vulnerabilities in Python, I need to upgrade my Python version to 2.7.15 or above.

Currently my application uses Jython Version 2.7.1b2, Which version of Jython I should update to be compatible for Python 2.7.15 or above.

Comment: You should use 2.7.1. See https://jython.github.io/download.

Comment: 2.7.1 was removed from http://jython.org and has some serious bugs.  I've been downgrading to 2.7.0 whenever I find 2.7.1 in use.

Comment: About "Jython to python version mapping": see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50965533/407651 and https://bugs.jython.org/issue2694